# htmlagilitypack select element and submit form

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I just started working with htmlagilitypack, and I am loving it so far.

I'm trying to select a radio button and submit a form using htmlagility.

Here is the structure of the website:

```
<form class="picker" action="link.html" method="POST">
    <ul class="selection-list">
        <li>
            <label>
                <span class="left-side">
                    <input name="id" value="t1" type="radio">
                </span>
                <span class="right-side">
                    Test1
                </span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span class="left-side">
                    <input name="id" value="t2" type="radio">
                </span>
                <span class="right-side">
                    Test2
                </span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span class="left-side">
                    <input name="id" value="t3" type="radio">
                </span>
                <span class="right-side">
                    Test3
                </span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I can get the form. Here is the code:

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(urlAddress);

// Get the form
var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@class='picker']");
```

How can I select, for example, the

Test2 and submit the form? Is it possible using htmlagilitypack or I need another library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var uri = // get uri from form;
var formVariables = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

// Populate your variables here; HtmlAgilityPack is useful for propagating existing form values
formVariables.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("id","t2"));

var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formVariables);

using (var message = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = HttpMethod.Post, RequestUri = uri, Content = formContent })
{
    // use HttpClient to send the message
    using (var postResponse = await client.SendAsync(message))
    {
        if (postResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Do something with string content
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the uri by string actionValue = form.Attributes["action"]?.Value; System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(actionValue); How can I get the new page generated after posting?

Comment: The new page is the response content from sending the message (e.g. client.SendAsync(message)).

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); var response = client.SendAsync(message); Response result is null and status WaitingForActivation. Is it correct?

Comment: SendAsync returns Task<HttpResponseMessage>. You will need to await the call. I'll edit the sample.